# stop exceuting other threads while cache refresh

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a functionality where need to run a job in background after defined time interval.
for this i used ScheduledExecutorService to execute the thread after certain time interval.

To store cache data i am using concurrent hash map.

ConcurrentHashMap

while the refresh is happening the other thread in app checks for cache and overwrites the map data.i have tried using synchroized but it didn't work.basically what i want to achieve is pause other process while cache refresh is happening.

Comment: Why is `synchronized` not working? Also you should show some code of what you have tried?

Comment: You do not need to pause the thread, in my opinion - a simple semaphore should do the trick and yes, that is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReentrantReadWriteLock to synchronize your read and write operations. In ReentrantReadWriteLock, multiple threads are allowed read & only one thread is allowed to write to your shared resource which is map in your case. If a thread is writing to your shared resource then other threads will wait for read/ write requests.

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();


readWriteLock.readLock().lock();

    // multiple readers can enter this section
    // if not locked for writing, and not writers waiting
    // to lock for writing.

readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();


readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();

    // only one writer can enter this section,
    // and only if no threads are currently reading.

readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
```

Hence while your cache is refreshing no other thread will be allowed to read/write to your map but when no thread is writing then multiple threads will be allowed to read map.